# Prove that minimum spanning tree is a tree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing, trees

From the the Wikipedia page [Minimum spanning tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree):

> A minimum spanning tree is a spanning tree of a connected, undirected graph. It connects all the vertices together with the minimal total weighting for its edges.

Let G be a connected, undirected graph, and let H be a connected subgraph of G such that "it connects all the vertices together with the minimal total weighting for its edges". How do I prove that H is a tree?

It's pretty easy if you think about it, if H is not a tree it will have one or more "useless" edges and those could be removed, resulting in a tree with a smaller total weighting for its edges. I can't find a way to write this down formally though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make an argument that if $H$ is not a tree then $H$ contains a cycle, therefore there is an edge that can be removed without disconnecting $H$.  This contradicts the assumption that $H$ has minimal edge weight.

Comment: And how do I prove that it contains a cycle?

Comment: I know, but that's what I'm trying to prove. That H is a tree.

Comment: Ah ok I see, thanks!